# Java enum implementing interface as custom annotation parameter

Tags: java, enums, annotations

I'm creating an custom annotation with parameters. Parameters I want to use are enums that implement an interface. There are few enums that are candidates to b used as this annotation's parameter. Here are some code examples:

Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    String getSomething();
    int getMore();
}
```

Enum example:

```
public enum MyEnum implements MyInterface {

    VAL1("some1", 1),
    VAL2("2val", 22);

    private String something;
    private int more;

    private MyEnum(String something, int more) {
        this.something = something;
        this.more = more;
    }

    public String getSomething() {
        return something;
    }

    public int getMore() {
        return more;
    }
}
```

I want to implement an annotation with parameter that can be retrieved as multiple MyInterface values. Let's say annotation looks like this:

```
@MyAnnotation(MyEnum.class)
```

or

```
@MyAnnotation(MyEnum.values())
```

So I can further retrieve it and pass it to a method that accepts Collection parameter.

How do I implement an annotation with a parameter so I can retrieve all values of enum as MyInterface type?

I was trying to do it like this:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    Class<? extends Enum<?> & MyInterface> myValues();
}
```

So I could do:

```
Collection<MyInterface> desired = Arrays.asList(... .getAnnotation().myValues().enumValues());
```

but this syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use union types in an annotation member, so you'll have to give up on that idea.

But frame challenge: why do you even care that the implementer has to be an enum?

What I assume you care about is that something can give you a finite set of implementations. An enum is one way to achieve that, but why be overly restrictive if someone wants to give you a list of values some other way?

I'd add a new interface which can provide a collection of values.

```
interface MyInterfaceValueSource {
    List<MyInterface> values();
}
```

The enum gets a very simple implementation that just calls `MyEnum.values()`.

```
class MyEnumValueSource implements MyInterfaceValueSource {
    @Override
    public List<MyInterface> values() {
        return Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values());
    }
}
```

Your annotation can then be altered to accept one of those

```
@interface MyAnnotation {
    Class<? extends MyInterfaceValueSource> value();
}
```

and example of its usage would be

```
@MyAnnotation(MyEnumValueSource.class)
```

Now if someone wants to provide a list of values but *not* implement it as an enum, they have the flexibility to do that.

```
class ExampleValueSource implements MyInterfaceValueSource {
    @Override
    public List<MyInterface> values() {
        return Arrays.asList(
            new MyInterfaceOne(), new MyInterfaceTwo()
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and a nice solution example! I see this approach means new ValueSource class has to be created for each source. And I'll have to create new instance of ValueSource to call values() method where I'm handling the annotation. But I guess this is what has to be done to deal with java annotation's limitations.